# Lazy import React Router Loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

After spending some time going through ReactJs and React Router (^v6) tutorials and docs, I stumbled upon a question - how can I `lazy` (lazily) import loaders and actions for `Routes`?

Here I have an `EditContact` component which is a default export. The same file has an async function for the react router loader and it is only a named export. When I import this component, I can import it lazily as this is the default export. However, that is not the case with my loader function.

I understand that "React.lazy currently only supports default exports" and am aware of the workaround to use an intermediate module for named exports. Can anyone please advise if my approach below to import loader function and lazy import only components is OK?

EditContact.jsx:

```
import React from "react";

export async function loader({ params }) {
  console.log("Contact Id =>", params.contactId);
  // Fetch contact details for the contact id
}

export default function EditContact() {
  return (
    <div>Todo: add/edit contact here</div>
  );
}
```

Router.js

```
import React, { lazy } from "react";
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
// import the loader
**import {loader as EditContactLoader} from "./Contact/EditContact";**

const Home = lazy(() => import("./Home"));
const Root = lazy(() => import("./Root"));

**const EditContact= lazy(() => import("./Contact/EditContact"));**

export const AppRoutes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <MyError />,
    children: [
      {
        errorElement: <MyError />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Home /> },
          ...
          {
            path: '/contact/:contactId/edit',
            element: <EditContact />,
            loader: EditContactLoader,
          },
          ...
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { AppRoutes } from "./App/Router";
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <RouterProvider router={AppRoutes} />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's almost a year since the question was asked, but I was trying to solve the same problem today and came across this page. Adding my solution here in case someone else is looking for it.

Solution 1: If the build target supports top-level await

```
{
  path: '/contact/:contactId/edit',
  element: <EditContact />,
  loader: (await import("./Contact/EditContact")).loader,
}
```

Solution 2: If the build target does not support top-level await

```
{
  path: '/contact/:contactId/edit',
  element: <EditContact />,
  loader: async (args) => {
    const loaderFn = (await import("./Contact/EditContact")).loader;
    if (!loaderFn) return null;
    return await loaderFn(args);
  }
}
```

In the second case, I'm not sure if there's a performance penalty for importing the module every time the loader is called. I'm assuming it should be fine since the module will be cached by the browser after the first load. I don't see any other way of importing the loader function lazily. I'll be glad to find out if someone has a better solution.